# How can we write the condition(s) in If block in Express-Handlebars?

Tags: conditional-statements, express-handlebars

I am using the Express handlebars and I am stuck at the point to compare the values in IF ELSE block.Is there built in helper? I spent a lot of time to find the solution but I didn't get that. Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this.
Reference:

> https://code-maven.com/handlebars-conditionals

Solution:
To make equal  '==' condition between two values using Express Helperbars do following steps.

1- Create helpers

**hbs.js**

```
module.exports = {

    if_eq: function(a, b, opts) {
        if (a == b) {
            return opts.fn(this);
        } else {
            return opts.inverse(this);
        }
    }
}
```

2- Register these Helpers in **app.js** file

```
// Handlebars Helpers
const {
  if_eq
} = require('./helpers/hbs'); //path to hbs.js file

// Handlebars Middleware
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
   helpers: {
    if_eq:if_eq
  },
  defaultLayout: 'main'
}));
```

3- Use if_eq helper in your HTML code.I am using to check radio button if gender is 'male' and similar to 'female' case.

```
    {{#if_eq idea.gender 'male'}}
            Female<input type="radio" class="form-control" name="gender" value="female">
            Male <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="gender" value="male" checked>
          {{else}}
            Female<input type="radio" class="form-control" name="gender" value="female" checked>
            Male <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="gender" value="male" >
{{/if_eq}}
```